# How can multiple regular expression matches in a single line of text be extracted and printed in a unix script

Tags: regex, perl, unix, sed, awk

I have a file with a single line as follows

```
blah blah <myxml>123</myxml> blah blah blah <myxml>5645</myxml> blah blah blah blah
```

Assuming that I have worked out a regular expression to find occurrences of `<myxml>.*</myxml>`, how do I write a unix script to extract and print all the xml fragments embedded in my single line?

i.e. To result in the following output:

```
<myxml>123</myxml>
<myxml>5645</myxml>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a good job for `grep`:

```
$ grep -Po '<\w*>\d*</\w*>' file
<myxml>123</myxml>
<myxml>5645</myxml>
```

In the expression,

- `<\w*>` matches any `<word>` and `</\w*>` any `</word>`.
- `\d*` matches any amount of numbers
- `grep -Po` is used to perform **P** erl regular expressions and **o** nly print the matched results.

Answer (score 2):

Using Perl oneliner, assuming your tag names will be having no space in it.

```
cat input.txt | perl -ne "$\=$/; print for /(<\S+?>\d+<\/\S+?>)/g"
```

Comment: You don't really need `cat` as `perl` can read directly from the file.

Comment: This question is tagged `unix`. You will regret using double quotes in your command like that.

Comment: @mob I use Windows! and tested it with `unxutils`. That's why I have `"` with me :(

Answer (score 0):

Using grep you can do:

```
s='blah blah <myxml>123</myxml> blah blah blah <myxml>5645</myxml> blah blah
grep -o '<[^>]*>[^<]*<[^>]*>' <<< "$s"
<myxml>123</myxml>
<myxml>5645</myxml>
```

Comment: thanks - I've had a number of replies and ended up using a different solution - but thank you very much for your response and I am sure it will be useful to others too!

Answer (score 0):

Using positive look ahead and behind.

```
$ grep -oP '(?<= )<[^ ]+(?= ) ' file
<myxml>123</myxml> 
<myxml>5645</myxml>
```

Look for a word which:

- has a space before it
- starts with `<`
- and ends with a space.

Comment: thanks - I've had a number of replies and ended up using a different solution - but thank you very much for your response and I am sure it will be useful to others too!